# SwiftUI Firebase Profile Picture current code

Tags: firebase, user-interface, swiftui, firebase-storage, profile-picture

I have been studying Firebase for a month and understand Auth and Firestore well enough for a beginner. Storage is a bit harder. I just want an Hstack with my users
profile pic  and message to be added to a list of messages when written.

EXAMPLE

the message

I don't know how to apply to my UI I guess. Please only kindness in answers, I don't want to be belittled or spoken sharply to. It has taken me 2 years to ask a question on here again because of how cruelly I was treated before making me feel foolish.

I bought a book (because I'm having ZERO luck finding CURRENT examples for this online) that gave me these codes but false starter codes which became confusing.  Also can't find Firebase help for 2023 and their current codes.

This is code I have but the View is embarrassing because I was following the book and it stopped so I don't even understand what it left me with. I don't know if showing my code will even help but I know it is requested a lot.

so This is what I have as View Model, and then I added my View after which makes no sense to me because the book just left me there.

```
class PostViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var posts = [Post]()
    
    let storageReference = Storage.storage().reference().child("\.  
    (UUID().uuidString)")
    
    private var databaseReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts")
    
    
    func Task() async{
        await self.addData(description: "", datePublished: Date(), data: Data())
    }
    
    
    func addData(description:String, datePublished:Date, data:Data) async {
        
        do{
            _ = try await storageReference.putData(data, metadata: nil){
                (metadata, error) in
                
                guard let metadata = metadata else{
                    return
                }
                
                self.storageReference.downloadURL {
                    (url, error)  in
                    
                    guard let downloadURL = url else{
                        //
                        return
                    }
                    self.databaseReference.addDocument(data: ["description":  
    description, "datePublished": datePublished,"ImageURL": 
    downloadURL.absoluteString])
                }
            }
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                
                
            }
            
     
    }
}
```

```
 ______________________________________________
 THE VIEW FOLLOWING ‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️
______________________________________________
```

```
struct PostView: View {
    @FirestoreQuery(collectionPath:"Posts")
    var posts: [Post]
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = PostViewModel()
    
    @State var tf = ""
    

    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack{
            
            
            List(posts){post in
                
                
                Text(posts.description )
                    .font(.title)
                Text("Published on \(post.datePublished? .formatted() ?? "")")
                    .font(.title)
                
            }
            .frame(minHeight:150, maxHeight: 300)
            
       
             
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a couple of things that you may want to look at to clean things up (that may not directly solve your problem). 1) You probably don't want a function called `Task()` -- there's already something in Swift called `Task`. And, generally, we name our functions with lowercase letters. 2) your interpolated string for `storageReference` is invalid -- look at your syntax with `\.` 3) In SwiftUI, where you own the ObservableObject, you should use `StateObject`, not `ObservedObject`. 4) You have `posts` defined in `viewModel` -- it shouldn't be defined again in your view.

Comment: How wonderfully kind of you to take that time! I will look into all those things, you pointed out things I know but get lost sometimes, and things I didn't know so again thank you so much! I was really wondering about the Task thing. It was in the book and I didn't understand where it went.